# Java scanner taking inputs infinitely

Tags: java

I am new to programming and java and wanted to create my own array sorting program. I know it's not a good code. But when I run this, the Scanner class is taking inputs forever.

This check variable is causing problems but I don't know-how.
Can some please find out the problem? I am unable to find it. Thanks.

```java
1. public class apple {
2.   public static void main(String args[]) {
3.     int[] num = new int[5];
4.     int check = 0;
5.     int temp = 0;
6.     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
7.     System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers randomly");
8. 
9.     for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
10.       num[i] = input.nextInt();
11.     }
12. 
13.     do {
14.       for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
15.         if (j < num.length - 1 && num[j] > num[j + 1]) {
16.           check++;
17.           temp = num[j];
18.           num[j] = num[j + 1];
19.           num[j + 1] = temp;
20. 
21.         } else if (j < num.length && num[j] < num[0]) {
22.           check++;
23.           temp = num[0];
24.           num[0] = num[j];
25.           num[j] = num[0];
26. 
27.         }
28. 
29.       }
30. 
31.     }
32.     while (check < 100);
33. 
34.     for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++) {
35.       System.out.println(num[x]);
36.     }
37.     System.out.println(check);
38. 
39.   }
40. 
41. }
```

Comment: The `check` variable is only ever referenced after you're completely done with the scanner. What makes you think the two are related?

Comment: Consider using indentation in such a way that it makes your code more readable, instead of less.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you're stuck in your `do while` loop forever, because `check` isn't getting to 100.  The best way for you to be sure would be to step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo when I lower the check value the program is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your check increment outside you if/else if condition, that way if neither of those conditions is true the do/while loop will still complete:

```
for (int j=0;j<num.length;j++) {
    if(j<num.length-1 && num[j]>num[j+1]) {
        //check++;
        temp=num[j];
        num[j]=num[j+1];
        num[j+1]=temp;
    
        
    }
    else if(j<num.length && num[j]<num[0]) {
        //check++;
        temp=num[0];
        num[0]=num[j];
        num[j]=num[0];
        
    }
    check++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can tell me why do while loop is affecting the input loop.

Comment: AFAIK it isn't. When I run your code it accepts 5 numbers and does its sorting and completes. You are entering each number on a new line? (pressing enter after each number)

Comment: Yes I am pressing enter after each number.

Comment: What OS are you using? In linux and other unix OS's you can still keep entering data to standard in when the program is not accepting it. As is the case if your application is stuck in the do/while loop indefinitely. If you place a `println` prompt in your input loop this would be evident. Alternately as suggested by @Dawood you could step it through in a debugger.

Comment: In most terminals, there's no visual distinction between "I'm waiting for user input" and "I'm running a computation that hasn't finished". You might consider putting a print statement such as "Input received" after the scanner loop, so you can tell the difference

Comment: Yes this was the problem after taking input my program could not get out of do while loop(bcz of check variable not reaching 100) so it seemed like its asking me to put input again and again . I checked by putting println after input loop . Thanks guys for your help and teaching me something new .